# NullPointer Exception in Onclick

Tags: java, gwt, actionlistener, onclicklistener

I'm facing NullPointer exception on click on a button in GWT, Could someone suggest me how to go ahead and debug the issue ? I have posted the snippet of the code here.

I have a form which creates a movie ticket on create, cancel if user decides not to. On cancel it loads back to the first form successfully but parent form buttons throw null pointer exception on click.

Note: These parent buttons were works just fine if i don't load createMovie page.

createMovie.class

```
public void init( ClickListener listener )
    {

    // code ...
    // ........

     cancel.addClickListener( listener );  
     createMovie.add( header );
     createMovie.add( table );
     createMovie.setHeight( "663px" );

     initWidget( createMovie ); 

    }
```

In FocusWidget.class

```
    public void addClickListener(ClickListener listener) {
    if (clickListeners == null) {
      clickListeners = new ClickListenerCollection();
      sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
    }
    clickListeners.add(listener);
    }

// code

 @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
      case Event.ONCLICK:
        if (clickListeners != null) {
          clickListeners.fireClick(this);   ------->>> LINE 102
        }
        break;

      case Event.ONBLUR:
      case Event.ONFOCUS:
        if (focusListeners != null) {
          focusListeners.fireFocusEvent(this, event);
        }
        break;

      case Event.ONKEYDOWN:
      case Event.ONKEYUP:
      case Event.ONKEYPRESS:
        if (keyboardListeners != null) {
          keyboardListeners.fireKeyboardEvent(this, event);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

In ClickListenerCollection.class

```
public void fireClick(Widget sender) {
    for (ClickListener listener : this) {
      listener.onClick(sender);
    }
    }
```

Errors:

```
[ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ClickListenerCollection.fireClick(ClickListenerCollection.java:34)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FocusWidget.onBrowserEvent(FocusWidget.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1308)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventAndCatch(DOM.java:1287)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1255)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: This is probably not the source of your troubles, but `addClickListener` is deprecated, you should really use `addClickHandler`instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things i have done to fix,

I had cancel button in both forms (parent & child) and upon calling 'cancel' in createMovie.class ( child ) i was removing the parent form. So when i attempted to press 'cancel' in child form ( createMovie ) the listener was passing Null.

Fix

```
            if ( childFormLoaded )
            {
                if ( panelsControl.containsPanel( createMovie.class.getName() ) )
                    panelsControl.removePanel( createMovie.class.getName() );
            }
            else
            {
                if ( panelsControl.containsPanel( ParentClass.class.getName() ) )
                    panelsControl.removePanel( ParentClass.class.getName() );
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

A NullPointerException means that you're trying to run something on a null object. (Well, not exactly, but that's basically it.)

First of all, learn how to read a stack trace. It's a very important skill. Basically, go down the stack until you find a file that is yours. In this case, it's FocusWidget:102. Since I don't know which line 102 is, I'll just guess.

Since you seem to be implying that the error is in that code snippet, and anything in the if statement can't be null since you're checking for it, my guess is that somehow the argument "listener" is null. I'm not sure, though. It'd be helpful if you could give us the entire block of code that's causing the issue, i.e. the scope around line 102.

Comment: Added the code line 102 & i am reading the stack and trying to find the prob. It works if i don't go to createMovie form.

Comment: Ah. Well, there are two element there: clickListener and "this." If the former isn't null, it must be the latter. So somehow, "this" is null.